# Create a batch file to change the power options in Windows 7

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to create batch file and place it on the desktop to change the power options in Windows 7?  Specifically I have the computer set to sleep after 30 minutes.  Now that I use "Serve To Me/Stream To Me" apps I want to quickly be able to change the power settings to allow continuous operation and then quickly change the power settings back to 30 minute sleep when i'm done using the streaming apps.  How is this done? Can it be done?

Thanks
Gary

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/90415/prevent-sleep-in-scripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying the Power Scheme using Batch Files in Windows XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800713/modifying-the-power-scheme-using-batch-files-in-windows-xp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create or modify the power schemes you want to use.

Launch RegEdit and navigate to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\User\PowerSchemes
```

Look through the schemes and find the GUID (long strings of characters) of the scheme you want to use.

Create a batch file like so:

```
@echo off
powercfg -s (GUID of the Scheme you wish to switch to.)
pause (Optional)
```

Name the batch file(s) appropriately.

You will make one batch file for each scheme you want to switch to.

Comment: Instead of going through RegEdit, another way to find the GUID for each scheme is to run the following command on the command line:    `Powercfg /List`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Available power schemes:
echo/

set i=0
set "options="
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=:()" %%a in ('powercfg /L') do if "%%b" neq "" (
   set /A i+=1
   set "options=!options!!i!"
   echo !i!. %%b
   set "scheme[!i!]=%%a"
)

echo/
choice /C %options% /N /M "Select desired scheme: "
powercfg /S !scheme[%errorlevel%]!
echo/
echo Power scheme set
```

Perhaps you need to change the `"tokens=2,3 delims=:()"` FOR options to match your version or locale. I developed this code in my Windows 8.1 Spanish version; this is an output example:

```
Available power schemes:

1. Certificado ENERGY STAR
2. Alto rendimiento
3. Economizador

Select desired scheme: 1

Power scheme set
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both for your quick replies and solutions.  Lance I used yours because it was simpler, after all I'm not familiar (a true rookie) with command line programming.  The following code is what worked.

(The following turns off the sleep feature.)

```
@echo off
powercfg -SetAcValueIndex^
 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c^
 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20^ 
 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da^
 000
TIMEOUT /T -1
```

(The following sets the sleep to activate after 1800 seconds = 30 minutes.)

```
@echo off
powercfg -SetAcValueIndex^
 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c^
 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20^
 29f6c1db-86da-48c5-9fdb-f2b67b1f44da^
 1800
TIMEOUT /T -1.
```

Thanks Again

Gary

Comment: Glad you got it working, Gary.  I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer since it's the one you used.

Comment: @Lance, how do I do that?  I tried to press the up arrow but it won't let me do that since I don't have 15 posts.

Comment: @Lance I'm sorry Lance, I don't see that.

Comment: Hmmm.  There should be a grey check mark below the up and down arrows.  If not, no big deal.  Thanks.

Comment: @Lance, Ok, it was there, I was looking elsewhere.  Checked it for you.

Comment: @Lance, So I noticed that that change alone won't prevent my computer from sleeping.  I believe at the same time I have to keep the monitor from from turning off also.  I have the registry keys but can't figure out how to change it in the same batch file as the sleep code.  How do i combine the code.  The additional entries are:                 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99^
 3c0bc021-c8a8-4e07-a973-6b14cbcb2b7e^
 0

Comment: I thing you should create one profile that has all the settings and options you want, then just switch to and from that one.  I don't think you can combine profiles.

Comment: @Lance, I figured out my mistake, I forgot to put in the scheme guid entry, I only had the sub, setting and setting index.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool [Insomnia](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/delay/2009/09/30/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep/) to prevent your windows to go to sleep. It works for Windows 7/8/10 and comes with source code.

Another way is to use the command line tool powercfg.

**Never go to standby:**

```
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
```

**Go to standby in 15 minutes:**

powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 15