# Can I deactivate a monitor/display with node/electron?

Tags: node.js, electron

I, I'm writing an app with electron (http://electron.atom.io/). I would like to deactivate the monitor/display of the pc and only activate it again, when something in the app happens (for energy-saving). Is there a way to do this?
The only think I found, is the powerSaveBlocker (http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/power-save-blocker/) which doesn't help me...

Comment: Following [Aakash answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261513/2269874), this is a good solution: [Create a batch file to change the power options in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807801/create-a-batch-file-to-change-the-power-options-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use native system APIs to do this, on Windows you can use one of the solutions proposed in [Turn on/off monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713498/turn-on-off-monitor).

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can do that is by executing batch files from electron/node in Windows , shell scripts in Linux and whatever MAC OS uses to execute commands.

These scripts would contain the OS level commands to turn on/off the display which are easily available .

When to fire these scripts would depend on your application logic .